# detect a not responding thread and terminate it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, kill-process

Sometimes the background thread runs slow and goes like, not responding, responding, not responding ...

Is it possible to detect that and then terminate it and then restart it?
I make the threads like this. the Form3 just contains a web browser control which only navigates and search the web document.

```
Thread ab1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
ab1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
ab1.Start();

private void ThreadProc()
{
    Form frm = new Form3(currentAB);
    frm.ShowDialog();

}
```

Comment: Show your work also.. People can't help you without seeing your program.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are doing in the background thread? I think it would be a better idea to stop it from not reposinging, rather then just terminating it.

Comment: A thread can't go "Not responding", processes go. Do you mean thread?

Comment: Why don't you fix the real problem?

Comment: You cannot non-cooperatively kill threads. Don't use Thread.Abort without doing a Google search for why it can't be reliably used.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use a Timer on a Thread and call it every certain amount of seconds, check if your thread is dead.

Systems.Threading.Timer class would help you in that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/swx5easy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try  this  this will check only if the thread isalive but does not means that will detect if the thread is blocked on a long runing operation

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     Thread ab1;   
     public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
        Thread ab1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        ab1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        ab1.Start();
        bool isAlive = true ;
        TimerCallback tmrCallBack = new TimerCallback(CheckStatusThreadHealth);  
        System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(tmrCallBack,isAlive,2000,2000);
     }
     public void CheckStatusThreadHealth(object isAlive)
     {
         isAlive = ab1.IsAlive ;  
     }
     private void ThreadProc()
     {
         Form frm = new Form1();
        frm.ShowDialog();

     }
```

hope this help

Comment: Could you please explain this a little?
Does this mean that if the thread doesn't answer every 2 seconds it is terminated? or do i have to use ab1.dispose(); in the ChechStatusThreadHealth?

Comment: this will  check only if the thread isalive but  does not  means that will detect if the thread is blocked  on a long runing operation

Comment: if  not  isAlive  thats  means  that your thread was terminated correctly  or  has ended with exception. you can easily start  a new thread as the latest was garbage collected